# What damage is done by document.write()?

Tags: javascript, dom

What bad things happen at the moment `document.write()` is invoked?

I've heard bits and pieces about `document.write` having an adverse impact on the DOM or on the use of Javascript libraries. I have an issue in front of me that I suspect is related, but have not been able to find a concise summary of what damage the method does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use of `document.write()` will break a web page - **destroying and overwriting the entire DOM** - if it's called after the document has finished being parsed.  This is considered a poor use of `document.write()` and is/was the reason for criticism of a lot of older scripts.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    document.write("Oops!");
}
```

Generally though, it's acceptable and rather widely used at parse-time to add something dynamically to the page in a synchronous manner:

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("Well I'll be, your browser supports JavaScript!");
  </script>
</div>
```

It's mostly used by ad publishing services for adding the advertisements to a page, some Google APIs also use it.

Answer (score 8):

**Page blocking**, that's enough or a reason when it's used improperly.

When you do document.write, as Andy said, it's **synchronous** meaning you have to wait on it before continuing with the rest of the page.

I don't want your site to hang up just because your ad server is down.  Unfortunately, this is the case with SO, the ADs on the right use document.write using a script from another server that, if down, blocks the page from loading until it times out.  This delay, because of `document.write` and a slow (often third party) ad server is **far** too often the reason a site is slow to load.

Side rant: Advertisements gets you money from views, ok good, you need to make a living.  But don't be **dependent** on them from a technical perspective, as in their server is down, your site is FUBAR...do ads in a non-blocking way, there are many ways besides `document.write` to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah I got fed up of the ads on here blocking the rest of the page, so I now have `127.0.0.1 ads.stackoverflow.com` in my hosts file

Comment: +1 for the side rant, `ads.stackoverflow.com` seems to have trouble on a regular basis (mostly mornings GMT).  Not the best use of `document.write`.  :-)

Comment: I wrote a lib that allows you to load document.write scripts async: http://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture

Comment: @noah - Question though, if you're bringing in jQuery, why would you be using `document.write` at all?

Comment: writeCapture works with 3rd party scripts (Virtually every ad server out there uses document.write). Also, you don't have to use jQuery with writeCapture.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeUyH/) to to show a live example of what Andy E meant.

Basically the paragraph element won't be visible anymore because `document.write()` overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will prove it:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.write("Because I will overwrite everything.");
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, I won't render anymore.</p>
```