# Adsense loading inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, adsense

How would google know if you were using an iframe on one website to show another web page that contains Adsense. If the iframe loads the window, shouldn't Adsense just think it was loaded separately. I know it's against TOS and all just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from anything else, it's going to hurt your traffic. Adsense essentially scrapes your source pages so it can figure out which adverts to display. If you think about it from that point of view it should be obvious how they would find out.

If you're trying to dynamically add your Adsense units into the middle of your content, I have a solution that I am just about to post once I find the original question someone else asked.

Comment: fyi - here's the answer i was referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418041/add-javascript-into-a-html-page-with-jquery/9486596#9486596