# Google Adsense in Colorbox in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox, adsense

I am trying to putting some Adsense Ads inside a color box and have done below:

```
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_load', function(){
    var $ads = jQuery('<div style="width:728px; height:90px; background:#fff; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" id="adsenseColorbox"><script type="text/javascript"><!--google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5435441464221407";/* APRO_728x90_textonly */google_ad_slot = "0595008022";google_ad_width = 728;google_ad_height = 90;//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script></div>'); 
    jQuery('#cboxContent').prepend($ads); 
});
```

the result turns out to be:

```
<div id="cboxContent"...>
<div style="width:728px; height:90px; background:#fff; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" id="adsenseColorbox"></div>
...
</div>
```

Could someone please help to get this Google Adsense work in Colorbox? Thanks.

Comment: Solved! Using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418041/add-javascript-into-a-html-page-with-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add javascript into a html page with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418041/add-javascript-into-a-html-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try making `$ads` just a string. Drop the `jQuery()` bit around it.

Comment: `code`jQuery(document).bind('cbox_load', function(){
 var $ads = "<div style="width:728px; height:90px; background:#fff; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" id="adsenseColorbox"><script type="text/javascript"><!--google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5435441464221407";/* APRO_728x90_textonly */google_ad_slot = "0595008022";google_ad_width = 728;google_ad_height = 90;//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script></div>"; 
 jQuery('#cboxContent').prepend($ads); 
}); `code`
@Oldskool
but it's not working.

Comment: Well, no it won't work with that syntax, because you're using double quotes both as the boundaries as well as in the content. Try using single quotes.

Comment: that will just give me an empty div#adsenseColorbox

Comment: Solved! Using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418041/add-javascript-into-a-html-page-with-jquery