# Javascript: document.write to add external content?

Tags: javascript, document.write

Page `a.com` loads a javascript file from `b.com` like this:

```
<script src="http://b.com/file.js"></script>
```

`b.com/file.js` adds some content to `a.com`.

The `file.js` is like this:

```
document.write("<script ... <link rel=\"stylesheet\" ... <div> ... <form> ...");
```

But I know `document.write` is not good. But what are the alternatives? I don't think it's "ok" to add complete html code inside document.write ... or not?

Comment: This link might help you:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418041/add-javascript-into-a-html-page-with-jquery

Comment: So should I add this `<script src="http://b.com/file.js"></script>` inside a div? I am not sure if I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "not good" about using `document.write` here, especially when you want to add in some `<script>` to the page. If you are just using it to add DOM elements, you can consider using some [DOM manipulation methods](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Event_Handling).