# how to update time regularly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```
function timeClock()
{
    setTimeout("timeClock()", 1000);        
    now = new Date();
    alert(now);
    f_date = now.getDate()+" "+strMonth(now.getMonth())+" "+now.getFullYear()+" / "+timeFormat(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());
    return f_date;
}

<span class="foo"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(timeClock());</script></span>
```

alert(now); gives me the value every second but it is not updated in the html. How can I update the time on the html without refresh the page?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes in your code. Without the use of `var` infront of your variable declarations, you leak them into the global scope.

Also, the use of `document.write` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559189/what-damage-is-done-by-document-write).

Here's how I would do it:

**JavaScript:**

```
function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date(), // current date
        months = ['January', 'February', '...']; // you get the idea
        time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(), // again, you get the idea

        // a cleaner way than string concatenation
        date = [now.getDate(), 
                months[now.getMonth()],
                now.getFullYear()].join(' ');

    // set the content of the element with the ID time to the formatted string
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = [date, time].join(' / ');

    // call this function again in 1000ms
    setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
updateClock(); // initial call
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="time"> </div>
```

Comment: You should probably pad the `now.getMinutes()` call with leading zeros.

Comment: Little improvements:
now.getMonth()+1 should be sufficient instead of passing months array.
and
to get double digit minutes, seconds etc:
("0" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2)

Comment: @abhy Thanks for your advice, it helps me a lot!!

Comment: says too much recursion

Answer (score 6):

**setInterval(expression, timeout);**

The function setTimeout is intended for a single timeout, so using setInterval would be a more appropriate option. SetInterval will run regularly without the additional lines that Ivo's answer has.

I would rewrite Ivo's answer as follows:

**JavaScript:**

```
function updateClock() {
  // Ivo's content to create the date.
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = [date, time].join(' / ')
}
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Try it out yourself! https://jsfiddle.net/avotre/rtuna4x7/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN').item(0);
x.innerHTML = f_date;
```

try putting this code block instead of `return` statement, i haven't test it but it will probably work

Comment: First time documrnt.write is showing the undefined value.[ 23 Feb 2011 / 7.47 PM ISTundefined]. After a second it shows me the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

There may be something in timeago jQuery plugin you can hook into, but I haven't honestly tried...

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.foo').html(f_date);
```

place this inside your `timeclock()` function

**untested**

```
    function timeClock()
    {
        setTimeout("timeClock()", 1000);        
        now = new Date();
        alert(now);
        f_date = now.getDate()+" "+strMonth(now.getMonth())+" "+now.getFullYear()+" / "+timeFormat(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());
       $('span.foo').html(f_date);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use setInterval rather than setTimeout:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: it is advised to avoid `setInterval()` have a look here http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think your setTmeout function has the wrong variables, the first one should be a function not a string, that confused me for a bit. Basically you need to write to the span tag when you run the function.

I created a jQuery version in a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean. Didn't have your strMonth function but you get the idea. I also changed the alert to console.log but you can remove that line.

http://jsfiddle.net/5JWEV/

Answer (score 0):

**Straigt Javascript time format / update**

1: create month converter func
2: create time func
3: create update func
4: create outPut func

```
    // month converter from index / 0-11 values
function covertMonth(num){
  let months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  // look into index with num 0-11
  let computedRes = months[num];
  return computedRes;
}

// time func
function Time(){
   // important to get new instant of the Date referrance
  let date = new Date();
  this.time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  this.year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  this.day = date.getUTCDate();
  this.month = date.getUTCMonth();
  this.currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString() + ' ' + covertMonth(this.month) + ' ' + this.day + ' ' + this.year;
  return this.currentTime;
}


 function timeOutPut(){
  let where = document.getElementById('some-id');
  where.textContent = Time(); // 1:21:39 AM Dec 17 2017
}

   // run every 5secs
setInterval(timeOutPut, 5000);
```

Comment: Add some description

Answer (score 0):

I used @soloproper setInterval concept @Ivo Wetzel overall answer, my update is all about formatting the time as required. **Reduced Programming Lines**

```
<div id="liveClock"> </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
        updateClock();
});

function updateClock() {
   document.getElementById('liveClock').innerHTML = new Date().format("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function timeClock()
{
    setTimeout("timeClock()", 1000);        
    now = new Date();
    alert(now);
    f_date = now.getDate()+" "+strMonth(now.getMonth())+" "+now.getFullYear()+" / "+timeFormat(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());

    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = f_date;

}

<span id="foo"></span>
```