# JSP - How do get time to constantly update by ms

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

I am attempting to write an example JSP page for myself (very new to jsp), and have gone over an example to write one, but how do I get time to consistently update?

here is my snippet of code:

```
<body>
    <%
        java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
                "HH:mm:ss:SS z MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    %>

    <h1>
        Current Date and Time:
        <%=df.format(cal.getTime())%>
    </h1>
</body>
```

By the way i'm using a tomcat server to deploy this

Comment: Run this in a while(true) loop?

Comment: @smk have you made web development? No? Then please avoid such comments.

Comment: It's more related to Javascript (client-side) than Java (server-side).

Comment: The tomcat info is not relevant in order to analyze the problem.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know what anyone needed. I'm freshly new to jsp and web development with stuff like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function updateYourTime() {
        var now = new Date(), 
            months = ['January', 'February', '...']; 
            time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(), 

            date = [now.getDate(), 
                    months[now.getMonth()],
                    now.getFullYear()].join(' ');

        document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = [date, time].join(' / ');

        setTimeout(updateYourTime, 1000);//This method will call for every second
    }
    updateYourTime(); // initial call
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091888/how-to-update-time-regularly)  for details

```
<div id="currentTime"></time>
```

Comment: @Vnge did you checked my answer

Comment: how do i call the js function from my jsp?

Comment: @Vnge in script tag write updateYourTime(); .It will call automatically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26595/discussion-between-vnge-and-psr)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to show clock in your pages?

you can use java script.
[here is an example](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=297)

Answer (score 0):

to show server clock in clients jsp use this javascripcode with java

Add a label where ever you want to show the server Time

```
<strong>Server Time&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><label id="timelable"></label>
```

And then add the following java script code at the end of the jsp inside the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
        var jsVar=  <%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()%>;
        var timeZoneOffset=<%=java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())%>;

        jsVar=jsVar+timeZoneOffset;
        function myTimer() {
        jsVar=jsVar+1000;
        var d = new Date(jsVar);
        var t=d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("timelable").innerHTML = t;
}

        </script>
```

Thats it now you will see the server time running in you jsp.