# How to add clock in View of MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have the following lines of html code  in  jquery mobile header to display time. It is static now as it refreshes only when page is refreshed. How I can periodically update the time without page refresh ?

```
<div id="updateTime">
    <span>@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</span><br />
    @{
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        string formatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("t", ci);
    }
</div>
```

Comment: What about an AJAX call, or use client time.

Comment: This was answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091888/how-to-update-time-regularly. You will need to use javascript and the setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jClock in previous project and it's always worked well:
https://github.com/dsparling/jclock

After installing the plugin js file you can call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jclock').jclock({format: '%I:%M:%S %p'});
});
```

Sample Styling:

```
.jclock
{
    background-color:Navy;  color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 64pt;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #fff;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```