# Converting 24 Hours time to 12 Hours In Javascript With Seconds Running

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have been researching about this around Internet but couldn't find a solution. I have this script which displays time in **Monday, March 16, 2015, 16:59:40** format which you can see is a 24 hours format and Seconds are not running. The script is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
var d = new Date(),

    seconds = d.getSeconds().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
    days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
return days[d.getDay()]+', '+months[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getDate()+', '+d.getFullYear()+', '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds+' '
}
</script>
```

And HTML is

```
<span id='para1'></span>
```

You can see the current code running at https://jsfiddle.net/g70rsr1L/
All I want is to convert 24 hours format to 12 hours and a running seconds script within it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you NEED to use javascript? PHP solution is really fast and easy.

Comment: As of im using blogger host, i can't use PHP, so im in need of JS :(

Comment: Do you mean with `running secondes`: [how to update time regularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091888)

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888498/4583548) I found in similiar question

Comment: Yeah running seconds, to be more specific, seconds changing on screen itself not when we reload the page

Answer (score 0):

this from your code, it can help you:

```
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
var d = new Date(),

    seconds = d.getSeconds().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
            hour = d.getHours() >= 12 ? parseInt(d.getHours()) - 12 : d.getHours(),
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
    days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
return days[d.getDay()]+', '+months[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getDate()+', '+d.getFullYear()+', '+hour+':'+minutes+':'+seconds+' '+ ampm;
}
```

call this function in setInterval  function and keep interval of one second.