# Stopwatch JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to dev and I'm trying to implement a stopwatch to my html body using Javascript

```js
var c = 0.0;

function tempo() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = c += 0.1;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myTimer = setInterval(tempo, 1000)">Lancement!</button>

<p id="test">Clic ici</p>

<button onClick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Arret!</button>
```

But is there any function or method to increment the seconds, minutes and hours automatically? Or do I have to count with `setInterval`?

edit:
its what i'm actually doing ! taking time when click on a button and when click again get the interval between both click...

```
<button onclick="test()">ICI</button>
let debut;
let fin;
let ouiNon = false;
function test() {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let currentSec = currentTime.getSeconds();
    let currentMin = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
    if (ouiNon == false) {
        debut = currentTime;
        ouiNon = true;
        console.log("debut ok");
        console.log(debut);
    } else {
        fin = currentTime;
        ouiNon = false;
        console.log("fin ok");
        console.log(fin);
    }
    console.log(fin - debut);
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update time regularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091888/how-to-update-time-regularly)

Comment: `setInterval` is evaluated in milliseconds. Hence a good option.

Comment: Any reason why you’re using `onclick` attributes instead of `addEventListener`?

Comment: `+= 0.1` can give you issues. Instead, use `c = (c*10 + 1) / 10`

Comment: *increment the seconds, minutes and hours automatically* No.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a stopwatch using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318822/how-to-create-a-stopwatch-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use date to get second, minute and hour.

```
var date = new Date();

date.getSeconds(); //get seconds
date.getMinutes(); //get mintes
date.getHours();   //get hours
```

but to check this you need setInterval method also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current time and extract the parts you want from it.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentSec  = currentTime.getSeconds();
var currentMim  = currentTime.getMinutes();
var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
```

Comment: Thank you, this help me, i'm trying different way to use currentTime

Comment: open the developer tools in google chrome and play around in the console. It has nice completion of methods.