# When using document.write to load a different css stylesheet, browser refreshes infinitely

Tags: javascript, ios, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I am trying to have two different stylesheets on my wordpress blog, so that one stylesheet is used when the page is accessed via the web, and the other stylesheet is used when the blog content is accessed via our iOS app.  Right now we are appending ?app=true to URL requests from our iOS app in hopes that in our blog we could search for this string and load a different stylesheet.  We are using a JSON API plugin so that our iOS app can programmatically pull our blog posts and display them in a web view in the iOS App.

In my wordpress blog I am using javascript that looks for ?app=true in the URL, and if so, load a different stylesheet.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var location = window.location.href;
if(location.indexOf("?app=true") > -1) {        
document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"appstyle.css\" />");
}
</script>
```

This code is placed within the  tags in the header.php file of my wordpress theme.

The stylesheet that I am trying to use is called appstyle.css and is located in the same directory as header.php.

The issue that I'm having is that with this code it reloads the browser page infinitely.  The issue seems to be with the document.write function, as without that the webpage loads fine (although it obviously isn't loading the appstyle.css stylesheet).

I have also tried this if statement:

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf('?app=true') === 0)
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there a better way to load different stylesheets depending on if it is loaded in an iOS app vs the web?  Is there something I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Don't use [`document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2559286/352796).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
location === window.location
```

in the console.

It will output `true`. Which shows that the global variable `location` is already set and points to the current [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/window.location) object of [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/window). With your code you're changing that variable, by assigning a new value, which triggers a browser reload.

To fix it, just use another name for your variable, e.g.:

```
var currentLocation = window.location.href;
```

Or put your code in a self-executing function, to separate it from the global scope:

```
(function (){
  var location = window.location.href;
  if(location.indexOf('?app=true') > -1) {        
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appstyle.css" />');
  }
}());
```

Comment: Thanks - Changing to "var currentLocation = window.location.href;" fixed the browser refresh issue.  However, not it's not actually reading the appstyle.css stylesheet.  I also do not see it create the html in the page source.  I can only see the original stylesheet in the html "<link rel='stylesheet' id='standard-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/standard/style.css?ver=3.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />"

Comment: The url being passed is http://localhost:8888/?app=true or for an individual post: http://localhost:8888/?p=29?app=true

Comment: I've marked your question as correct, because you fixed the browser refresh issue.  I've created a new question for the new issue (the appstyle.css stylesheet isn't being loaded) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007048/load-different-css-stylesheet-using-javascipt-reading-from-url-variable   -- I'd appreciate your help greatly!

Answer (score 4):

This line has a syntax error:

```
document.write("<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appstyle.css" />");
```

Try changing it to this:

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appstyle.css" />');
```

or do the proper escaping

```
document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"appstyle.css\" />");
```

Comment: Sorry - I pasted in the wrong line of text.  I did the proper escaping  with this line document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"appstyle.css\" />"); but am still having the issue

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using document.write, remember to call document.close() onload or soon after.

Comment: What would I use instead of document.write?