# Load different CSS stylesheet using JavaScript reading from URL variable

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, wordpress

I am trying to have two different stylesheets on my wordpress blog, so that one stylesheet is used when the page is accessed via the web, and the other stylesheet is used when the blog content is accessed via our iOS app. Right now we are appending ?app=true to URL requests from our iOS app in hopes that in our blog we could search for this string and load a different stylesheet. We are using a JSON API plugin so that our iOS app can programmatically pull our blog posts and display them in a web view in the iOS App.

In my wordpress blog I am using JavaScript that looks for ?app=true in the URL, and if so, load a different stylesheet.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var currentLocation = window.location.href; 
    if(currentLocation.indexOf('/?app=true') > -1) {        
        document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"appstyle.css\" />");
    }
</script>
```

You can take a look at http://blog.meetcody.com and view the page source. You will see this code snippet in-between the  tags.

The issue that I'm having is that the above code doesn't actually load the appstyle.css stylesheet.  If you take a look at http://blog.meetcody.com/wp-content/themes/standard/appstyle.css?ver=3.4.2 you can see that I'm testing this by setting the background: black in the body {} tag

```
body {
background: black;
}
```

Whereas, in style.css at http://blog.meetcody.com/wp-content/themes/standard/style.css?ver=3.4.2 the body background color is #F2F0EB; in the body {} tag

```
body {
    background: #F2F0EB;
}
```

How can I pass a URL variable such as ?app=true and when that is passed, I load a different stylesheet?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `var currentLocation = window.location.href; = window.location.href;` should be `var currentLocation = window.location.href;`

Comment: You could also try `if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?app=true') > -1) {` Anyway, it might be better to google "responsive design".

Comment: Thanks, edited the code, but the stylesheet isn't loading.  Also we're already using responsive web design and media queries for CSS.  The reason we want two stylesheets, is so that we can maintain one stylesheet for the mobile-web and another stylesheet for iOS web views.  With media queries alone, we wouldn't be able to distinguish between a web view loaded in an iOS app, and mobile safari.  Would definitely appreciate the help here.

Comment: If I load your page (http://blog.meetcody.com/), it still has the error, as my Firebug tells me. If I use Firebug Console with `if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?app=true') > -1) {` (as I suggested), it works.

Comment: Really? You got it to work?  I am now using the exact code you suggested on blog.meetcody.com.  There are no errors with the code, but it's still not using the appstyle.css stylesheet.  With the document.write href as /appstyle.css it couldn't find the stylesheet, so now I'm also using a direct link. Now it's not throwing errors in the console, but I don't see the stylesheet loading.  Did you actually see it working?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I just posted it. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way to approach your problem is to employ [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) techniques. These allow you to address different resolutions appropriately.

The basic CSS looks something like the following...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    // CSS for iPhone
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    // CSS for iPad
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900x) {
    // CSS for desktop
}
```

The take-away is that you won't need to load different stylesheets for different platforms. You'll have one stylesheet that works in every situation. It can even work for platforms you haven't specifically targeted.

The team the built the new Boston Globe site were my introduction to RWD. Here's [a breakdown of what they did](http://upstatement.com/blog/2012/01/how-to-approach-a-responsive-design/).

Comment: Thanks.  We're already using responsive web design and media queries for CSS.  The reason we want two stylesheets, is so that we can maintain one stylesheet for the mobile-web and another stylesheet for iOS web views.  With media queries alone, we wouldn't be able to distinguish between a web view loaded in an iOS app, and mobile safari.  Would definitely appreciate the help here.

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but is there any reason why you can't use conditional comments to load different stylesheets?

Comment: I believe conditionals comments are only for IE. But we also need to load a different stylesheet vs just change a couple CSS rules.

Comment: So, I assume that you're using PHP (since WordPress is mentioned in your tags). You can do server-side browser checks and load completely different stylesheets based on that.

Comment: The scenario is this: Load one stylesheet when user uses mobile safari, load another stylesheet when user uses our native iOS app and loads a web view.  As far as I know there is no browser check to load a different stylesheet for a web-app?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some things with the Firebug console on your site. So, what actually worked was the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?app=true') > -1) {
    var fileref=document.createElement("link");
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href", "http://blog.meetcody.com/wp-content/themes/standard/appstyle.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
</script>
```

(This code was adapted from [Dynamically loading an external JavaScript or CSS file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)).

Since your are loading other stylesheets and I guess you overwrite their rules, you have to load this stylesheet AFTER all the others. So put this code at the end of your document or in a `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

You could also sniff out the user-agent string. This way you wouldn't have to pass anything. In most cases I wouldn't recommend it usually but with such a specific case you can safely do it without a ton of code.

```
// Define what "webview" is
var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

// See if this user is coming from it
if (is_uiwebview = true) {
// Your code to make the <link> with a proper href
// Raul's would work perfectly
};
```

Again, as everyone else said make sure it loads things after your web-only stylesheet.
Also not entirely sure the `= true` is needed.