# Validate number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is below. I have a user input a radius and it display a area of a circle. I need to make sure the user does not input negative or 0 radius. what should i add to make this work?

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>Find the area and circumference of a circle</title>
 </head>
  <body>
 <script language="JavaScript">
  function CalculateArea(){
    var radius =document.form1.txtRadius.value;
    document.write("<P>The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI) + "                  </p>");

}
</script>
<form name=form1>
    Enter the radius of circle:
   <input type="text" name="txtRadius" size=10>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='CalculateArea();'>  
</form>
 </script>
 </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the 'greater than' sign in an 'if' statement?

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0" />` -- omg magic! Although you'll need to listen to a `submit` event on the form, not a `click` event on the button.

Comment: You have all sorts of problems with your code, like `name=form1`. Where are the quotes? Also bad indentation. Camel casing HTML attributes. Probably will work, but bad practice. Might make you think you can use `onClick` in JavaScript. You can't. `document.write()` won`t work with XHTML, so you can't just copy your function off of the page and transport it to your new project. What if it's XHTML? `<script type='text/javasript' src='external.js'>`: If you use external JavaScript and CSS, it will be put into the Browser's cache, for faster loading.

Answer (score 0):

See more on `document.write()` function :

- [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)
- [What are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)
- [What damage is done by document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559189/what-damage-is-done-by-document-write)

Don't use the write function. Prefere to create new element with `document.createElement("p")`.

**DEMO :** http://jsbin.com/qabup/1/edit

```
function print() {
    var p = document.createElement("p"),
        text = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ", ");
    p.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById("console").appendChild(p);
    return text;
}

function CalculateArea() {
    var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRadius').value); // String to int.

    if (0 < radius)
        print("The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI));
    else
        print("Error message.");

    return false;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    Enter the radius of circle:
    <input type="text" id="txtRadius" size="10" />
     <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalculateArea()"/>
    <div id="console"></div>
</div>
```

### Old solution :

Try this :

```
var radius = parseInt(document.form1.txtRadius.value); // String to int.

if (0 < radius)
    document.write("<p>The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI) + "</p>")
else
    document.write("<p>Error message.</p>")
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using `0 < radius` and not `radius > 0`, which is much more readable?

Comment: To me it's more easy with smaller value on the left. [ I think like this : (1, 2, 3, 4... 8) 1 < 8 ]

Comment: More importantly, why have you not corrected OP's (mis)use of `document.write`?

Comment: Thankyou! It was helpful and it worked! just wondering would i be able to do a alert rather than a text message? how should i replace that. thanks again sir! I am new to javascript and apologize for any silly mistakes/questions!

Comment: Niet the dark absol can you please elaborate how it is wrong? the code is still returning output.

Comment: I got the answer to the question.

Comment: The JSbin is brilliant! This site is genius. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give your `input` an `ID`:

```
<input type="text" name="txtRadius" id="txtRadius" size="10" />
```

Use something like this to check if the value is less than or equal to 0:

```
var num = document.getElementById('txtRadius').value;
var radius = parseInt(num);

if (radius > 0){
    alert('number is not less than 0');
else {
    alert('number is less than 0');
}
```

**Note:** `document.write` is a bad habit. Instead, you can use `someElement.innerHTML`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/3739658) for more info why it is a bad habit.

Comment: Updated answer for you!

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to do it with JavaScript:

```
function isInteger(x) {
    return (Math.round(x) === x);
}

function CalculateArea(){
    var radius = document.form1.txtRadius.value;
    if(isInteger(radius) && radius > 0) {
        document.write("<P>The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI) + "
    } else {
        whatever you want to do if it's no integer or zero
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails. `inInteger` is being passed a string (`.value`), `Math.round` returns a number, and `number === string` cannot be true.