# Printing JavaScript to HTML doc

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript homework assignment requests "display the results in the document window". I am assuming it means to print out the JS answers on an HTML doc and not a pop-up.

I can get this code to work in the console, but have absolutely no idea how to get it to print on an HTML doc. From what I've read, using document.write is bad form and "return" doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var mm = (i * 25.4);
  console.log (i + " inches = " + Math.round(100 * mm) / 100 + " millimeters"); 
}
```

Also, is there a way for all the numbers to print out the 10ths place integer? Notice in the results below, at "5 inches," it only prints the whole number, I'd like it to print 127.0 to keep the numbers consistent.

```
3 inches = 76.2 millimeters
4 inches = 101.6 millimeters
5 inches = 127 millimeters
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who said `document.write` is bad form?

Comment: @Leeish
I found out here, on these 3 links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559189/what-damage-is-done-by-document-write

http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `document.write` you can create a HTML element and then add a value to it with Javascript. Also you can use `toFixed` to format the number. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var mm = (i * 25.4);
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML += i + " inches = " + (Math.round(100 * mm) / 100).toFixed(1) + " millimeters <br />";
}
```