# document.write is killing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I created a timer and did not notice the document.write was killing the page because everything was working great. However, when the timer goes to 0, it only displays what is in the document.write function rather than everything else in my page.

This is what is killing the page and only the text in ()'s is what is showing..

```
document.write("The NFL Season is here!!");
```

How can I make this so that the timer would stop and this text displays or this text can display on my page without killing the rest of the code?

Here is my full code to demonstrate how I am doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cdtd () {
            var nflSeason = new Date ("September 10, 2015 08:30:00");
            var now = new Date();
            var timeDiff = nflSeason.getTime() - now.getTime();
            if (timeDiff < 0) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                document.write("The NFL Season is here!!");
                //Run any code needed for countdown completion here.
            }

            var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
            var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
            hours %= 24;
            minutes %= 60;
            seconds %= 60;

            document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
            document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
            document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
            document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds;

            var timer = setTimeout('cdtd()',1000);
        }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="countdown_out">
<div id="countdown_title">NFL Season Opener Countdown</div>
<div class="countdown_position">
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Days</div>
        <div id="daysBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Hours</div>
        <div id="hoursBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Minutes</div>
        <div id="minsBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Seconds</div>
        <div id="secsBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Related - What damage is done by document.write()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559189/what-damage-is-done-by-document-write)

Comment: This is *exactly* why you should not be using `document.write()`.  Once the page is fully loaded, it **destroys** everything and overwrites the DOM.  If you want to write to the DOM, use `.innerHTML` (or similar).

Comment: P.S. Do **not** do `setTimeout('cdtd()',1000)`.  This uses `eval` and is very bad practice.  Instead do `setTimeout(cdtd,1000)`.

Comment: How can I do this. I followed the link James Thorpe added and tried that and it doesn't work. How can I do innerHTML with it?

Comment: @Becky: The same way you *already* are: `document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;`

Comment: So what could I put in this box of code that will read when the timer is less than 0 it will add that div?

Comment: just create a div in your page `<div id="page_message"></div>` and in javascript replace `document.write()`  with `document.getElementById("page_message").innerHTML = 'The NFL Season is here!!';`

Comment: @Sushil How could I set this, so that this div isn't always showing unless the timer has ran out though?

Comment: give `style='display:none'` to the div and when you're showing the message just unhide it using `document.getElementById("page_message").style.display = 'inline';`

Comment: But placing the `getElementById` where it is just shows the content. It doesn't read when the timer has ran out. That is why that doc.write was in here `if (timeDiff < 0) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                document.write("The NFL Season is here!!");
                //Run any code needed for countdown completion here.
            }`

Comment: Or did you mean to put the `document.getElementById("page_message").innerHTML = 'The NFL Season is here!!';` in that if statement?

Comment: yeah that is what i meant.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried that and it worked. Thanks! I will award you the answer if you answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: great. let me post that as an answer

Comment: I've posted my answer @Becky. please upvote and accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as everybody suggested. `document.write` will clear everything from the `DOM`.
the best way to write this would be to have a `DIV` in your HTML and set that div in your javascript code.

here's what your **HTML** should look like

```
<div id="page_message" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="countdown_out">
<div id="countdown_title">NFL Season Opener Countdown</div>
<div class="countdown_position">
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Days</div>
        <div id="daysBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Hours</div>
        <div id="hoursBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Minutes</div>
        <div id="minsBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdownBox">
        <div class="countdown_time_category">Seconds</div>
        <div id="secsBox" class="countdown_time"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and update your **Javascript** code to look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cdtd() {
        var nflSeason = new Date("September 10, 2015 08:30:00");
        var now = new Date();
        var timeDiff = nflSeason.getTime() - now.getTime();
        if (timeDiff < 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            document.getElementById("page_message").innerHTML = 'The NFL Season is here!!';
            document.getElementById("page_message").style.display = 'inline';

            //Run any code needed for countdown completion here.
        }

        var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        hours %= 24;
        minutes %= 60;
        seconds %= 60;

        document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds;

        var timer = setTimeout('cdtd()', 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `document.write` only from synchronious code before page is fully loaded. Do not use it from timers, event handlers and scripts marked by `defer` or `async`. You have to use other way of changing DOM.