# Program for responding second click within 2 seconds of first

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a program which sees if a click is made within 2 seconds of previous click.
My Code for same is:

```
document.addEventListener("click",do,false);
var lastBack=0;
function do(e){
   if((new Date().getTime()-lastBack)<2000)
         { alert("you clicked within 2 seconds this time");}
   else         
         { document.write("Quickly click again");
          lastBack=new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

I just cannot figure out whats wrong with it but when i click, it just displays '*quickly click again*' and nothing else happens.Even it doesnt repeat the same line when clicked after long wait.

Comment: NEVER document.write after load. The page will be wiped

Comment: @mplungjan: its just for sake of asking question, not for real code

Comment: "do" is a reserved word, you can't call a function "do"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NEVER document.write after load. The page will be wiped
   [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)
   [What damage is done by document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559189/what-damage-is-done-by-document-write)
2. `do` is a reserved word. Rename the function or make it anonymous

```js
var lastBack = 0;

function doIt(e) {
  if ((new Date().getTime() - lastBack) < 2000) {
    alert("you clicked within 2 seconds this time");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Quickly click again";
    lastBack = new Date().getTime();
  }
}


window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  document.addEventListener("click", doIt, false); // assign click handler
},false)
```

```html
<span id="message"></span>
```

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for the working example but your code doesnt work when i save it and run in chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) but it does work on stackoverflow code snippet

Comment: You have to do it a page load event

Comment: I dont understand sir. Being more experienced, i request you to help me out

Comment: Please see update - tested in Chrome 68.0.3440.75 outside SO

Comment: Yes it is. If not then you are not inserting it correctly

Comment: It Worked! But i dont understand how using document.write() instead of your method was creating problems with JS interpretations

Comment: You can only use document write inline before the page has loaded